# Is the set of invertible upper triangular matrices open in $GL_n(\mathbb R)$? Is it open in the set of all upper triangular matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, matrices

I think the answer to the second question is yes, but can't quite prove this. I've no idea about the first part. I've done a few exercises of this kind but all have used the continuity of the determinant function and the same idea doesn't seem to work here. How do I do these?

Comment: No to the first (for $n>1$), any invertible upper triangular matrix is arbitrarily close to an invertible non-upper triangular matrix. Yes to the second, $GL_n$ is open, hence the intersection of this with the subspace of all upper triangular matrices is open in the subspace of all upper triangular matrices.

Comment: I understand the second part and also the intuition behind the logic in the first part. But how does one make the argument 'comes arbitrarily close to an invertible non-upper triangular matrix' more rigorous?

Comment: Given any invertible upper triangular matrix $T$ the matrix $T+\epsilon E_{nn}$ is not upper triangular for any $\epsilon\neq 0$ and is invertible for sufficiently small $\epsilon$. If the first space was open, then there would be some neighbourhood of $T$ that would remain invertible and upper triangular.

Comment: What is $E_{nn}$?

Comment: The matrix with zeroes everywhere except for a one in the $n,n$ position. However, I meant the $E_{n1}$ matrix (sorry), so please correct the above when reading it! Basically a one in the bottom left position of the matrix. Anywhere below the diagonal will do.

Comment: I got it. Sorry if I'm missing something, but is the $det$ of $\epsilon E_{n1}$ not zero for any $\epsilon$? In that case, $det(T+\epsilon E_{n1})=det(T)\neq 0\forall\epsilon> 0$. Am I mistaken or do I really need the 'for sufficiently small $\epsilon$' part?

Comment: No. You want to show that the first space is not open. One way is to pick a point in the set $T$ and then show a collection of points that are not in the set but arbitrarily close to the point. (cont.)

Comment: Thanks, got it finally now.

Comment: So, pick $A_n = T + {1\over n} E_{n1}$, a small perturbation. You can see that $A_n$ is never upper triangular, hence outside of the set for all $n$. And we have $A_n \to T$. (Oh, I forgot, for large enough $n$, $A_n$ is invertible (by, say, continuity of $\det$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set on invertible upper triangular matrices is actually closed in $GL(n,\Bbb R)$, since it is defined by the vanishing of a bunch of matrix entries (which entries are continuous functions of the matrix). If it were also open, it would be a union of connected components. But $GL(n,\Bbb R)$ has only two connected components (determined by the sign of the determinant); clearly the upper triangular matrices are no union of them.

Answer (score 2):

Olé Marc or why to do simple when we can do complicated.

Proof by a simple man: $I$ is invertible and upper triangular. For every $\epsilon >0$, $I+\epsilon E_{2,1}$ is invertible and not upper triangular.

I see that it is the proof of copper-hat

Comment: Yes of course, this is more direct. Maybe my point is that it is actually easier to see that this set is closed than that it is not open, because of the direct criterion for closedness (or openness), as being the continuous inverse image of a known closed (resp. open) set. I don't know any such direct (quantifier free) way of showing "not open".

Comment: Marc, I agree with you on your comment. Yet, i am not sure that the OP (for instance) can prove that the set of invertible upper triangular matrices is closed in $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ in a quantifier free way.